# Not able to crop the content outside the artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, artboard, crop

I am not able to crop the image which is outside the artboard.
I have tried all the methods available on the internet.
Which tells that make an object and with the help of Pathfinder tool but its not working or I am not able to do that.
I attached the
[File here](https://ufile.io/e9gac) .

Answer (score 1):

You can not apply pathfinder to an image unless you convert it into vectors.

- Make a rectangle above the image, the same size as the page
- Select the image and the rectangle
- **Menu Object** > **Clipping Mask** > **Make**

[image: mask]

Comment: Please can you make it, I have tried before but i failed! I attached the file

Comment: @Tommy There's an animation at the answer. The attached file has no image, if you want someone else testing on your file, save it as PDF and attache it again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are after but you can go to the VIEW menu and select TRIM VIEW, this will "crop" your artboard so you only see what is on the artboard.